# Each line into a file (XML as part of file)

Tags: text-processing

Here is a sample of the content in the file:

```
<:abc>test file name <:/abc>   XYZ  1122
```

XML content is pretty heavy and big.

Under the directory I am working in I want to create a sub-directory `XYZ` (second column) if not there, and under this sub-directory create the file `1122.raw` (third column) and have the XML content (`<:abc>test file name <:/abc>`) added to that file.

Comment: As you can guess this  a Q&A site, not script writing service. Tell us what you did or, how you plan to attack the problem and you will be pointed your flaws in that process or if there are better ways of doing it, you will be pointed those. But if you expect someone to write a script for you, probably not going to happen.

Comment: The sample is also a bit vague. Is the XML only one level, or can it be nested? Can there be newlines in the XML data? What delimiter is used between the columns? What characters can be found in second and third column?

Answer (score 1):

@MelBurslan's comment is correct, you shouldn't in general expect people to write scripts for you, as that's not what StackExchange is for.  But in this case, I had some time: here's one script that does what the question asks, assuming that the XML doesn't contain any newlines, and that the subdirectory and filename portions don't contain any special characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

my $nameRE = qr/[\w.]+/;

chomp;
m/^(.*)\s+($nameRE)\s+($nameRE)\s*$/ or do { warn "didn't match line $.: $_\n"; next };
my ( $xml, $dir, $line ) = ( $1, $2, $3 );

mkdir $dir;
open my $f, ">>", "$dir/$line.raw";
print $f "$xml\n";
close $f;
```

Save that as `process.pl` and run `./process.pl inputfile.xml`.